# Retrieving value based on matched dates

Tags: r, date, if-statement, matching, economics

I have two dataframes. The first ones containing Events with corresponding start and end times. The second one containing the prices of different ID's for every minute. Look below:

```
Event                       starttime             endtime
Change in Nonfarm Payrolls  2020-03-06 08:15:00   2020-03-06 09:00:00
Change in Nonfarm Payrolls  2020-02-07 08:15:00   2020-02-07 09:00:00
Change in Nonfarm Payrolls  2020-01-10 08:15:00   2020-01-10 09:00:00
Change in Nonfarm Payrolls  2020-01-10 08:15:00   2020-01-10 09:00:00
```

```
Price    date_time             ID
24813    2020-03-06 08:14:00   DJ
24763    2020-03-06 08:15:00   DJ
24750    2020-03-06 08:16:00   DJ
24725    2020-03-06 08:17:00   DJ
```

I would like to obtain the price and ID from the second dataset (for the starttime and endtime) and add it to the first one. I have tried using `ifelse` like this but it doesn't work.

```
df1$startprice <- ifelse(df1$starttime == df2$date_time, df2$Price, "no")
```

*Can someone help me out?*

**To reproduce the data:** (For the first Event the start and end time are included)

```
df1 <- structure(list(Event = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), .Label = c("Change in Nonfarm Payrolls"), class = "factor"), 
                    starttime = structure(c(1583478900, 1581059700, 1578640500, 1578640500, 1581059700), class = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt"), tzone = ""), 
                    endtime = structure(c(1583481600, 1581062400, 1578643200, 1578643200, 1581062400), class = c("POSIXct","POSIXt"), tzone = "")), row.names = c(NA, 5L), class = "data.frame")
```

```
df2 <- structure(list(Price = c(24813, 24763, 24750, 24725, 
                                      24746, 24735, 24755, 24735, 24735, 24744, 24762, 24763, 24773, 
                                      24773, 24778, 24832, 24856, 24845, 24842, 24902, 24934, 24854, 
                                      24888, 24914, 24922, 24875, 24896, 24853, 24834, 24845, 24886, 
                                      24872, 24844, 24846, 24860, 24812, 24791, 24767, 24765, 24756, 
                                      24745, 24791, 24800, 24789, 24787, 24887, 24876, 24911), date_time = structure(c(1583478840, 
                                                                                                                                    1583478900, 1583478960, 1583479020, 1583479080, 1583479140, 1583479200, 
                                                                                                                                    1583479260, 1583479320, 1583479380, 1583479440, 1583479500, 1583479560, 
                                                                                                                                    1583479620, 1583479680, 1583479740, 1583479800, 1583479860, 1583479920, 
                                                                                                                                    1583479980, 1583480040, 1583480100, 1583480160, 1583480220, 1583480280, 
                                                                                                                                    1583480340, 1583480400, 1583480460, 1583480520, 1583480580, 1583480640, 
                                                                                                                                    1583480700, 1583480760, 1583480820, 1583480880, 1583480940, 1583481000, 
                                                                                                                                    1583481060, 1583481120, 1583481180, 1583481240, 1583481300, 1583481360, 
                                                                                                                                    1583481420, 1583481480, 1583481540, 1583481600, 1583481660), class = c("POSIXct", 
                                                                                                                                                                                                           "POSIXt"), tzone = ""), ID = c("DJ", "DJ", "DJ", 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                          "DJ", "DJ", "DJ", "DJ", "DJ", "DJ", "DJ", "DJ", "DJ", "DJ", "DJ", 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                          "DJ", "DJ", "DJ", "DJ", "DJ", "DJ", "DJ", "DJ", "DJ", "DJ", "DJ", 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                          "DJ", "DJ", "DJ", "DJ", "DJ", "DJ", "DJ", "DJ", "DJ", "DJ", "DJ", 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                          "DJ", "DJ", "DJ", "DJ", "DJ", "DJ", "DJ", "DJ", "DJ", "DJ", "DJ", 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                          "DJ")), row.names = 62835:62882, class = "data.frame")
```

Thanks in advance!
Kind regards,
Jurgen

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can `merge` twice first with `starttime` and again with `endtime`.

```
merge(df1, transform(df2, start_time_price = Price)[-1], 
      by.x = 'starttime', by.y = 'date_time') |>
  merge(transform(df2, end_time_price = Price)[-1], 
        by.x = c('ID', 'endtime'), by.y = c('ID', 'date_time'))
```

If you want to keep all the rows of `df1` in the final output use `all.x = TRUE` in `merge`. Pipe operator (`|>`) has been introduced in R 4.1 if you have older version of R use -

```
merge(merge(df1, transform(df2, start_time_price = Price)[-1], 
      by.x = 'starttime', by.y = 'date_time'), 
  transform(df2, end_time_price = Price)[-1], 
        by.x = c('ID', 'endtime'), by.y = c('ID', 'date_time'))
```

Answer (score 2):

I'm assuming you are trying to add the `Price` and `ID` from the second dataset to the first dataset by matching the `date_time` of the second dataset to the `starttime` of the first dataset.

In that case it can be achieved using dplyr's `left_join`:

```
library(dplyr)
df1 %>% left_join(df2, by = c('starttime' = 'date_time'))
```

Output:

```
                       Event           starttime             endtime Price   ID
1 Change in Nonfarm Payrolls 2020-03-06 15:15:00 2020-03-06 16:00:00 24763   DJ
2 Change in Nonfarm Payrolls 2020-02-07 15:15:00 2020-02-07 16:00:00    NA <NA>
3 Change in Nonfarm Payrolls 2020-01-10 15:15:00 2020-01-10 16:00:00    NA <NA>
4 Change in Nonfarm Payrolls 2020-01-10 15:15:00 2020-01-10 16:00:00    NA <NA>
5 Change in Nonfarm Payrolls 2020-02-07 15:15:00 2020-02-07 16:00:00    NA <NA>
```

**Update:**
You would like to obtain the `Price` at the `starttime` AND the `Price` of the `endtime`.

You can pipe another `left_join` to the previous code, this time linking df1's `endtime` instead of `starttime`:

```
combinedPrice <- df1 %>% left_join(df2, by = c('starttime' = 'date_time')) %>% left_join(df2, by = c('endtime' = 'date_time'))
```

Output of `combinedPrice`:

```
Event                           starttime             endtime Price.x ID.x Price.y ID.y
1 Change in Nonfarm Payrolls 2020-03-06 15:15:00 2020-03-06 16:00:00   24763   DJ   24876   DJ
2 Change in Nonfarm Payrolls 2020-02-07 15:15:00 2020-02-07 16:00:00      NA <NA>      NA <NA>
3 Change in Nonfarm Payrolls 2020-01-10 15:15:00 2020-01-10 16:00:00      NA <NA>      NA <NA>
4 Change in Nonfarm Payrolls 2020-01-10 15:15:00 2020-01-10 16:00:00      NA <NA>      NA <NA>
5 Change in Nonfarm Payrolls 2020-02-07 15:15:00 2020-02-07 16:00:00      NA <NA>      NA <NA>
```

The start and end price are named `Price.x` and `Price.y` respectively. Also, we have 2 `ID` columns as result of the join. We can rename the Price columns and remove 1 ID column like so:

```
combinedPrice %>% rename('PriceStart' = Price.x, 'PriceEnd' = Price.y, 'ID' = ID.y) %>% select(-ID.x)
```

Output:

```
  Event                           starttime             endtime   PriceStart PriceEnd   ID
1 Change in Nonfarm Payrolls 2020-03-06 15:15:00 2020-03-06 16:00:00      24763    24876   DJ
2 Change in Nonfarm Payrolls 2020-02-07 15:15:00 2020-02-07 16:00:00         NA       NA <NA>
3 Change in Nonfarm Payrolls 2020-01-10 15:15:00 2020-01-10 16:00:00         NA       NA <NA>
4 Change in Nonfarm Payrolls 2020-01-10 15:15:00 2020-01-10 16:00:00         NA       NA <NA>
5 Change in Nonfarm Payrolls 2020-02-07 15:15:00 2020-02-07 16:00:00         NA       NA <NA>
```

Comment: Thank you so much! I'm wondering if you also know how to obtain the price at the starttime AND the price of the endtime? Resulting in two seperate price columns.

Comment: I'm now thinking to duplicate the `df2`, change the variable name of `Price` to `Price2`, and repeat this formula with `endtime` instead of `starttime`. This will probably work but is a bit cumbersome...

Comment: Updated post to answer your question :)